# Mystery noise in attic

Tags: attic, noise

My house is wood pier and beam, built in 1941. I’ve lived in it for 15 years and know its quirks inside and out. I had the roof replaced from shingles to standing seam metal. Sometime after this, I started hearing a noise that happens every now and then night or day usually only once or twice at a time coming from the general area of one corner of the attic. Because it happens so randomly, I’m not able to record it. It has a muffled juddering sound of wood on wood, loud at first then tailing off, like a vibration that loses its oomph. Sometimes I suspect it might be wind-related, like a suction. I don’t think it can be gutters or vent pipes as it is in no way metal sounding. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the timing seem to match large outside temperature changes?

Comment: Or when the sun hits or stops hitting the roof?

Comment: You could be hearing a critter. Look for scat and entry points to seal.

Comment: Yeah, most likely to be the standing seam sheets sliding as they expand and contract, as hinted at by crip659 and UnhandledExcepSean. One or the other or both of whom should write an answer.